# IFilterProvider Interface example error

Tags: 2010, connected-web-parts

I have deployed the code in  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.communication.ifilterprovider.aspx. When I connect this webpart to a list webpart, for some reason in the next function, connectedPart is null. Why this is happening?

```
        public override void PartCommunicationConnect(
            string interfaceName,
            WebPart connectedPart,
            string connectedInterfaceName,
            ConnectionRunAt runAt)
        {
            // Keep track of whether the Web Part is connected.
            if (interfaceName == "MyFilterProviderInterface")
            {
                _connected = true;
               _connectedWebPartTitle = SPEncode.HtmlEncode(connectedPart.Title);
            }
        }
```

And if IFilterProvider Interface is obsolete which one should I use? Is there some example like this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the Web Part that is being connected to is on another page,
>   connectedPart is null.

You can use [IWebPartParameters Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webparts.iwebpartparameters%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and it is clearly mentioned on [IFilterProvider Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.communication.ifilterprovider.aspx)

> [ObsoleteAttribute("Use
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.IWebPartParameters instead")]
>   public interface IFilterProvider

[Here](http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2011/03/how-to-build-a-consumer-web-part-in-sharepoint-2010-using-iwebpartparameters-that-works-with-html-fo.html) is a sample which using `IWebPartParameters Interface` to build a consumer web part.

Comment: The other Web Part is not in another Page, so I don't know why it is happening this. Thanks for the link about IFilterProvider Interface. It is not what I was expecting but I could have another use for this.